# regular expressions for selecting multiple lines

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, notepad++

i have a text file in a particular format..

```
!c_xyz|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyz
asdasda........................................................
asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
!c_abc|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyz...
```

I need a regular expression to reformat this file using Find and Replace - Visual Studio. The Desc field value has overflowed onto next lines. i need to move them back to the actual line. Final string should be like

```
    !c_xyz|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyzsdasda.........asdddddd..
    !c_abc|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyz...
```

I need an RE for "desc=" followed by anything until the next ! symbol

Comment: Just a suggestion, but Notepad++ does support RegEx find and replace, and may be a bit better suited for this type of data manipulation.

Comment: how can i do it on notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find `Desc=([^\|\r\n]+)[\r\n](([^!\r\n][^\r\n]+[\r\n])*)`, replace with `Desc=\1\2` and repeat until every line starts with `!` (you can test this using `^[^!]` as a search expr which should find nothing).

alternatively find `[\r\n]+`, replace with the empty string. thereafter find `!`, replace with `\r\n!`. this suggestion has 2 drawbacks. it temporarily produces very long lines which your editor (notably vs) may or may not have difficulties with and processes descriptions containing `!` incorrectly.

addendum:
your input seems to be fixed format up to the `Desc` section. if it is indeed, you can apply alternative #2, step 1, being followed by a search/replace run using `(!.{53}\|Desc=)`/`[\r\n]\1`.

Comment: On Visual studio, i used \n{(^[^!]).+} to find and \1 to replace.. did the job :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @X3074861X, you can use Notepad++.

Input:

```
!c_xyz|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyz
asdasda........................................................
asddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
!c_abc|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyz...
```

For the find and replace, select the mode as `Regular expression` with the options as follows:

`Find what`: `\r\n[^!]`

Leave `Replace with` blank.

Output:

```
!c_xyz|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyzsdasda........................................................sddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
!c_abc|crby=112|crdate=12jun11|mdby=112|mddate=12jun11|Desc=xyz...
```

Screenshot:

[image]